# Missing sequence number problem solved with XOR

Tags: algorithm, binary, xor

I'm trying to understand how the XOR operation managed to solve the problem  [PermMissingElem](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/3-time_complexity/perm_missing_elem/)

I know one of the properties of XOR is that:

```
A ⊕ B = C
C ⊕ A = B
C ⊕ B = A
```

```py
>>> 3 ^ 4
7
>>> 7 ^ 3
4
```

This can be repeated for any number of operations, in this case it was 2 numbers, but it could be 3, 4, 5... n

Another property is that:

```
A ⊕ A = 0
A ⊕ 0 = A
```

```py
>>> 3 ^ 3
0
>>> 3 ^ 0
3
```

But looking at the problem [PermMissingElem](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/3-time_complexity/perm_missing_elem/)
how was it possible to guarantee that the last operation would be exactly the number that was missing? Is there any literature on this algorithm, has anyone talked about it?

```py
A = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11]

missing_element = len(A)+1

for idx,value in enumerate(A):

    print(missing_element, value, (idx+1), ' = ', missing_element ^ value ^ (idx+1))
    missing_element = missing_element ^ value ^ (idx+1)
```

out

```
11 1 1  =  11
11 2 2  =  11
11 3 3  =  11
11 4 4  =  11
11 5 5  =  11
> 11 7 6  =  10
10 8 7  =  5
5  9 8  =  4
4 10 9  =  7
> 7 11 10 =  6
```

as can be seen:

```
11 ⊕ 7 ⊕ 6 = 10
7 ⊕ 11 ⊕ 10 = 6
```

Comment: A simple example is the best way to understand: `(1^2^4) ^ (1^2^3^4) = 3`. Therefore, `3` is missing in the first part. The only needed relations are `A^A=0` and `B^0=B`, together with commutativity and associativity of XOR `^` operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know, there is exactly one of each number in the input in range `[1..n+1]` except for one missing `k` and the fact that `a ⊕ a = 0`,

if you have another array `[1..n+1]`, without missing `k`,

then, on merging these arrays, we will have one big array with every number repeated twice, except `k`. So, if we XOR all elements of this array, each repeated element cancels itself and we will be left with `k`, which is your missing number.

Answer (score 1):

The XOR operation is commutative, the order of application does not matter.

Two XORs with the same value cancel each other.

So, starting from 0 and applying any sequence of XORs, followed by the same sequence that includes an extra element, only the effect of the extra element remains.

E.g. 0 ⊕2⊕3⊕1⊕5 ⊕1⊕2⊕3⊕4⊕5 has the same effect as 0⊕1⊕1⊕2⊕2⊕3⊕3⊕4⊕5⊕5, or 0⊕4.